# JQuery - How to add click for an element only on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener

I have two divs with a class `desktop` and `mobile`.
How can I add a click listener only for an element with a class `button` in a div with a class `mobile` . I try sth like

`$(".mobile .button").click(function(){...});` and `$(".mobile").find(".button").click(function() {...});`

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="desktop">
  <div class="button">
   <div> The same .... </div>
  </div>
 </div
 <div class="mobile">
  <div class="button">
   <div> The same .... </div>
  </div>
 </div
<div>
```

Comment: making a different button for different screen size and switching between those using @mediaQuery

Comment: I can't change the structure of HTML. This is the only example.

Comment: Either example you posted should work.  What seems to be the problem? Note that you have syntax errors in your html code.

Comment: $(".mobile .button").click(function () { .. some actions ...)} - nothing happend 
$(".mobile").find(".button").click(function () { ... some actions   }); - nothing happend

Comment: Did you try it after fixing your html code?  Works on my end.

Comment: My HTML is ok. I haven't mentioned that the code is written with Drupal 9.